# Linking other libraries into dynamically loaded libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, dynamic-loading

I am writing a library that is loaded dynamically by another progam. This library uses some Boost libraries (for example, thread). Is it possible to make it work somehow without recompiling the program in question?

If I use the link flags `-lboost_thread`, it doesn't work, because the program that uses this library would need to link the same Boost library, too. Using `/usr/lib/libboost_thread.a` also doesn't work, because the `.a` file isn't compiled with `-fPIC`.

I am using GCC under Linux.

Comment: Do you mean the program that loads your library would need to load the boost library at run-time?  You shouldn't need to *link* that library to the main application at build-time, it would just be a run-time dependency... right?

Comment: The program loads one dynamic library which I write. That library depends on Boost.

Comment: So is the problem that the program can't find the Boost libraries *at runtime*, so your library fails to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying again, I found that the problem was not what I described. The library didn't load for some other reason. I found that linking the library with `-lboost_thread` works, with the following conditions:

- gcc gives compiler warnings (possibly because the libraries are from the `-L` path which is not in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).
- When loading the library, it loads Boost automatically provided it can find them.